# Value discrepency between saved and restored model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

During training I am attempting to save the variables in a checkpoint file. I use the following code:

```
if step % 1000 == 0 or (step + 1) == FLAGS.max_steps:
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, 'model.ckpt')
    saver4=tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)

    a1=tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("local3/weights:0")
    a1eval=a1.eval()

    saver4.save(sess, checkpoint_path+"_4", global_step=step)
```

However, the evaluated variable `local3/weights:0` as `a1eval` and the same variable evaluated subsequently after restoring the checkpoint are different (I use two savers for testing, both of them restore the wrong value).
What can be going on?

Comment: How different are the values? This is hard to debug without more information.

Comment: Actually, I discovered the problem. The values saved are correct. The problem was when I restored them. The values restored were not the regular values, but the moving average values of the original variables.